# Wordpress theiaStickySidebar in Suga magazine theme behaving strangely when not logged in to wp-admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress

The sidebar is being positioned in the wrong position.

the sidebar is a sticky sidebar that uses **theia-sticky-sidebar** plugin, however i don't have this plugin installed but the theme **Suga magazine** has a sidebar builder that uses it.

Here's a link to the [website](https://calibbr.com/our-top-best-vinyl-records)

This is what it looks like when i'm logged out of the dashboard
[image]

This is how it's supposed to and how it looks like when im logged in to the wp-dashboard
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plugin called remove links from comments was messing with the HTML on the page. after tweaking the settings of this plugin the sticky sidebar functioned as intended.